# Rust syntax - lifetime highlighting

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting

It shows up in any snippet with explicit lifetimes - it formats lifetimes as though they were string literals

```rust
fn lifetimes<'a, 'b: 'a>(x: &'b &'a str) -> &'a str {
    *x
}
```

Google prettify seems to work here, so I am not sure what's going on:

https://rawgit.com/google/code-prettify/master/tests/prettify_test.html#rust

On Stack Overflow that code looks wrong:

```rust
// Single line comment
/* Multi-line (nesting not highlighted properly, sorry)
comment */

#![feature(code_prettification)]

use std::io::{self, Write};

impl<'a, T: 'a + ?Sized> Foo<'a, 'static> for Bar<'b>
where T: Iterator<Item = Box<Fn() -> u32>> {
    fn something(&mut self) -> u32 {
        if let Some(ref x) = self.foo("multi li\ne
s\tring") {
            panic!(r"\things is going wrong!");
            panic!(r#"Things is "really" goig\n wront!"#);
            panic!(r##"Raw strings are #"#fancy#"#"##);
        }
    }
}

pub type CowString<'a> = std::cow::Cow<'a, str>;

fn main() {
    let (i, r) = (1u8, 'c');
    let s = r#"Take a raw egg,
        "break" it (or the line),
        and beat it"#;
}
```

Comment: It is not a bug as the feature is not there. SE uses the built-in `rust` parser/lexer found in the core prettify. However, there is a specialized plugin, lang-rust, that isn't included. This can be verified [here](http://dev.sstatic.net/Js/prettify-full.en.js). That lang-rust file is mentioned in [this issue](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/issues/347). This needs to be a feature request to drop the built-in rust in favor of the lang-rust.